# iPhone switches to speakerphone when away from my face

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware

Since this morning I think, when I'm on a call and move my iPhone away from my face a bit, it seems to automatically switch to Speakerphone (the voice can be heard out loud) and it shows the number pad. When I get it close to my face again, it goes back to normal.

I have an iPhone 4S, latest iOS 6.1.3, clean install (no jailbreak).

I am not sure if this is a bug or a hidden feature I enabled by mistake - but this is very strange to me...

Comment: Can you post a link to screen shots of the screen in the before and after configurations? It seems like absolutely normal behavior when the proximity sensor is activated and deactivated, but perhaps I'm not getting the situation from the words correctly

Comment: Before or after what configurations? What I mean is when I move the phone away, the voice can be heard loud from the speakerphone, as if I tapped on "speaker" - but I didn't.

Comment: So, if you lay your phone on the table and dial someone's voicemail or another line you can keep open. Take a screen shot of the screen. Then move one finger or a pencil to cover the proximity sensor - see the screen go dark, then remove the finger or pencil. Take a second screen shot. You will know if there is a bug in the software or if you're inadvertently pressing the speaker button with your ear as the proximity sensor starts to disengage.

Comment: If I dial a number while flat on the table, it goes straight to speaker (and shows the digits pad). If I put my hand close, the screen goes black and the speaker turns off. Trying to take the screenshot hangs up the call.

Comment: Awesome - I'll send an answer - in short - you need to get it backed up, and seek service if an erase doesn't remedy the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you lay your phone on the table and dial a number, you should see this screen.

[image: call screen]

If you see speaker in blue, you might try tapping that part of the screen to see if you can return to the receiver for sound out. If so, hang up and repeat the call.

If all calls start with speaker, then you have a problem with the software or hardware. The [Apple troubleshooting](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/) web site might help, but I'd do this first:

1. Power down the phone and [test after a clean restart](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1702).
2. Back up the device (you will need to restore your data to the device after resetting things other than the settings in the immediate step below)
3. Go to the **Settings** app > **General** > **Reset** > **Reset All Settings**
4. Repeat the dial on the table test
5. Now erase everything on the phone **Settings** app > **General** > **Reset** > **Erase All Content and Settings**
6. Repeat the dial on the table test
7. [Restore the device using iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) to erase it.
8. Check the headset port and dock connector for foreign debris (or liquid damage)
9. [Get the hardware serviced by Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/contact/) (or other service provider) by going through the [Apple Troubleshooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcxQx.png) website mentioned before this list.

Comment: Well, it seems like a simple reboot did it. Strange bug, almost like a feature...

Comment: Oh wow - so we both forgot, kill the app, kill the session and make sure the problem is reproducible. Glad you posted. That will help many for sure!